# Why do we need to emphasize sufficient statistics in generalized linear models?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, maximum-likelihood, sufficient-statistics

In generalized linear models, $$p(y;\eta)=b(y)exp(\eta^TT(y)-a(\eta)) \\ \eta=\theta^T x$$we assume $x$ is the input variable and $y$ is the output and our target is to get  the distribution of input variable $x$ depends on
$\theta$,  i.e.$y=h_\theta(x)$.
Slides(e.g. Andrew Ng [cs229](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes2020fall/notes2020fall/cs229-notes1.pdf), ucb [cs294](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejordan/courses/260-spring10/other-readings/chapter8.pdf)) try to emphasize that $T(y)$ is a sufficient statistic, but get the parameter $\theta$ by Maximum Likelihood Estimate. I know sufficient statistics definition and Factorization theorem, but I can't understand these questions:

1. Why do we need to emphasize $T(y)$ is a sufficient statistic in GLM? Maximum Likelihood Estimate can always get a estimated result, does $T(y)$ is a sufficient statistic or not matter? When we can get the parameter $\theta$ by Maximum Likelihood Estimate, what can $T(y)$ help in the progress of estimating $\theta$?
2. When we want to get $h_\theta(x)$, why do we go to cumpute $E(T(y))$ ([cs229](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes2020fall/notes2020fall/cs229-notes1.pdf) say that $E(T(y))$ is one of three components of GLM)? In other words, why $h_\theta(x)=E(T(y))$? Just because $T(y)$ usually is $y$ in the exponential family(i.e. $T(y)=y$)? How to link $h_\theta(x)$ and $E(T(y))$? As for logistic regression, [cs229](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes2020fall/notes2020fall/cs229-notes1.pdf) gives that $$h_\theta(x) = p(y=1\mid x;\theta) = 0 \cdot p(y=0\mid x;\theta) + 1\cdot p(y=1\mid x;\theta) = E[y\mid x;\theta]$$, but it's a special distribution, what about other distributions?